# If our server has several IP and we use curl, what would the remote user see as the remote IP

Tags: curl, ip

The IP of the main server or the IP of the user of the script?

Say my server has 6 IP

```
123.123.123.122
123.123.123.123
123.123.123.124
...
```

One account, say in cpanel, has `123.123.123.124` as IP.

That account run a script curly formyip.com, for example.

What will it get? I think I can test this but if someone can give me a quick explanation that'll be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your cpanel account has a dedicated IP of 123.123.123.124, then that is the IP the other end would see the request come from.

Comment: Not as WHM feature but you could use IP masquerading to change the IP if you have access to your network configuration on the server

Comment: Oh curl actually has an option to curl based on specific IP.